# Subtracting Time From Timer In Unity Game C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, countdown, subtraction

Recently, I've been working on a racing game that requires the player to avoid Radioactive Barrels that *should* subtract 15 seconds if they happen to collide into them; Below is code for my 'Timer' script, and my Barrel Collision Script.

Timer Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeRemaining = 10;
    public bool timerIsRunning = false;
    public Text timeText;
 
    public void Start()
    {
        // Starts the timer automatically
        timerIsRunning = true;
    }
 
    public void Update()
    {
        if (timerIsRunning)
        {
            if (timeRemaining > 0)
            {
                timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
                DisplayTime(timeRemaining);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Time has run out!");
                timeRemaining = 0;
                timerIsRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }
 
    public void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay)
    {
        timeToDisplay += 1;
 
        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60); 
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);

        timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```

Next, is my Barrel Collision Script:

```
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;    

public class ExplosionTrigger : MonoBehaviour 
{
  
    public AudioSource ExplosionSound;
    public ParticleSystem Explosion;
 
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        Explosion.Play();
        ExplosionSound.Play();
        Timer.timeRemaining += 1.0f;      
    }  
}
```

Is there anyway I could subtract time by colliding into said Barrels from the Timer script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the `timeRemaining` exposed to other classes is using the static keyword.

`public static float timeRemaining = 10;`

By making the variable static, it can be referenced by other classes. If you would rather not expose the variable completely, you can make static setter/getters. The variable would then be `private static float timeRemaining = 10;` when using the setter/getter.

```
public static float TimeRemaining
{
     get{ return timeRemaining;}
     set { timeRemaining = value;}
}
```

If you happen to want to expose more variables or methods to your classes from a script, I would recommend either implementing the [Singleton Pattern](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) or possibly implement your own [Event System](https://medium.com/xrpractices/lets-build-a-custom-event-system-in-unity3d-d39f38b223d1) which uses the Singleton Pattern to pass events freely in your project. That way, you can subscribe and fire events for various scripts to listen for.

Comment: Holy smokes, that worked! I just used Timer.timeRemaning -= 5.0f; in my barrel collision script!!! Thank you so much! If I was able to upvote your reply (literally just got onto Stack so I'm not able to yet, lol), I most certainly would. Again, can't state this enough... THANK YOU!!!

Comment: No worries. Glad I was able to help out!

Comment: Should definitely **NOT** use ```+=``` inside a ```set```.  I fully expect ```TimeRemaining = 5;  var check = (TimeRemaining == 5);``` to set ```check``` to true.  Using ```+=``` destroys that axiom.

Comment: @Immersive True. I can remove the += and just use a normal setter. It does go against what is expected out of a setter/getter. For OPs use case I saw it as being an alternate solution for their personal project. **Edit**- updated the post by removing the += and utilizing the setter as it normally is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use `GetComponent<>()` to access the script from a different game object. You should set a GameObject variable, and drag the game object with the script on it. Add this to your barrel script:

```cs
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;    

public class ExplosionTrigger : MonoBehaviour 
{
  
    public AudioSource ExplosionSound;
    public ParticleSystem Explosion;
    public GameObject Timer;
    public float timeLoss;
    public Timer timer;

    void Start()
    {
        timer = Timer.GetComponent<TimerScript>();
    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        timer.timeRemaining -= 1f;
        Explosion.Play();
        ExplosionSound.Play();
    }  
}
```

You can change the values in the TimerScript using a period. Make sure to change TimerScript to the name of the script on the Timer game object.

Comment: Somebody already answered above, but I'm most certainly going to look at both suggestions; thanks man! I sincerely appreciate it!!! (and yea... idk what I was thinking with that one line. LOL)

Comment: @IsaacPaczkowski StackOverflow is made so multiple answers can be given ;) In my eyes the `static`/Singleton solution is ok .. for quick prototyping .. it can get out of hand easily in large developments .. so the cleaner and in long term better solution is this one, referencing the according Component correctly. I would change one thing though: Instead of GetComponent directly use the correct type for the field and use `public Timer timer;` and then directly `timer.timeRemaining -= timeLoss;`

Comment: @derHugo ,thanks for the info! I'm super new to programming, so knowing which solutions are better for quick testing vs. long term use is absolutely priceless. I know I'm supposed to avoid saying thanks in the comments here, but still, thanks. I truly appreciate all the input I've gotten on here so far.